# How to add Development Server Authentication settings in source control?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

Given the following

- Visual Studio 2015
- An ASP.NET Web Application (.csproj project)
- .NET 4.5.2
- IIS Express is enabled to debug and run the site
- Source control in TFS

When I enable the property Development Server > Windows Authentication, the setting cannot be persisted in source control.

Is there a way to configure this setting so that it is applied when retrieving the solution from Source Control?

Workaround: every developer has to enable this individually.

Note: this setting is stored in applicationhost.config

[image: project properties]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This setting is saved in .vs/config/applicationHost.config. Without checking this file to your source code control, the setting won't be shared. But of course, if you check it in, then all other settings (like bindings/ports) are also shared, and it might lead to other issues.

Mostly caused by IIS Express design, and have to get used to it.